# PHP & MySQL how to display data question

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to display my posts tags array `[0] => grill [1] => meat [2] => hot-dogs` with a comma separating each tag and was wondering how can I do this using PHP?

Stored in the database.

```
$page_tags = Array ( [0] => grill [1] => meat [2] => hot-dogs )
```

Desired output.

```
grill, meat, hot-dogs
```

Here is the PHP & MySQL code.

```
$page_tags = array();
$dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT tags.*, posts_tags.* 
                             FROM tags 
                             INNER JOIN posts_tags ON tags.id = posts_tags.tag_id
                             WHERE posts_tags.post_id= '" . $pageID . "'
                             AND posts_tags.user_id = '" . $userID . "'
                             GROUP BY tags.tag");

if (!$dbc) {
    print mysqli_error($mysqli);
} else {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc)){
        $page_tags[] = $row['tag'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you have an array `$page_tags`, you can use [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/implode) to output it separated by commas:

```
echo implode(", ", $page_tags);
```

Comment: `<pedantry> echo implode(", ", $page_tags); </pedantry>`

Comment: @fredley excuse my ignorance what is `<pedantry>`?

Comment: @askIT yes. @fredley is referring to his suggesting a minor change (the additional space after the comma)

Comment: @askIT it's worth looking into similar tags, `<irony>` and `<sarcasm>` in particular, they can be very useful.